# Azure SAS token always not authenticated when use by not whitelist IP

Tags: azure, sas, azure-blob-storage, token, azure-storage

my scenario is like this, frontend will hit to API with sending name for blob file, and the backend side in AKS will generate an SAS token for the blob file with expiry time 15 minutes. But when token send to frontend (SPA react) it cannot use have error not authenticated, but when put my browser IP to whitelist I can access the blob file. why this is happen, how to make sas token provide access for public at limited time without whitelist client browser IP?

my error

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
>
> `AuthorizationFailure`
> This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:b9efa22e-001e-004c-23f9-274133000000 Time:2023-12-06T04:07:47.4688222Z

this is my code look like

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using System;
using Azure.Storage;

namespace SAS.Container.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/get-sas")]
    public class GetSasAzureStorageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public GetSasAzureStorageController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

       [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult GetSasToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureStorageConnection");

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                {
                    return BadRequest("AzureStorageConnection is not configured in appsettings.json");
                }
                
                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                string containerName = "assets";
                string blobName = "myblob.png";
                var accountKey="myaccountKey";
               
                BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName).GetBlobClient(blobName);

                // Set permissions for SAS token
                BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
                {
                    BlobContainerName = containerName,
                    BlobName = blobName,
                    Resource = "b", // 'b' for blob
                    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)
                };

                // set permission read for SAS token
                sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

                // Generate SAS token
                BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
                {
                    Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential(blobServiceClient.AccountName,accountKey ))
                };
                var sastoken = blobUriBuilder.ToUri().ToString();
                return Ok(new
                {
                     sastoken
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an error what you facing?

Comment: Do you have any access-policies set on your storage-account that take precedence over your SAS URIs?

Comment: @Venkatesan this is my error. This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code>
<Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:b9efa22e-001e-004c-23f9-274133000000 Time:2023-12-06T04:07:47.4688222Z</Message>
</Error>

Comment: @Dai how I can check it?

Comment: @agungardiyanta In the Azure portal, check if storage account networking is Enabled on all networks.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make the sas token provide access for the public at a limited time without whitelisting the client browser IP?

If you need to access the `SAS` token for the public at a limited time without whitelisting the client browser IP, you need to change your network settings.

If your networking is enabled for selected virtual networks and IP addresses you can't able to access them in public.

***Portal -> your storage accounts -> Networking ->select the Enabled from all networks from portal.***

**Portal:**
[image]

Now you can use the same code to generate a **`SAS`** token to display the image.

**Code:**

```
var AccountName = "xxx";
var AccountKey = "xxxx";
var containerName = "xxxx";
var blobName = "xxxx";
StorageSharedKeyCredential key = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(AccountName, AccountKey);
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{AccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), key);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
{
    BlobContainerName = containerName,
    BlobName = blobName,
    Resource = "b", // b for blob, c for container
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
};
sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.All); // All permissions like(Read,write,add,list,create,SetImmutabilityPolicy,delete)
var Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(key).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(Sas);
var sasuri = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "?" + Sas;
Console.WriteLine(sasuri);
```

**Output:**

```
SAStoken = sv=2023-11-03&st=2023-12-07T07%3A00%3A17Z&se=2023-12-07T07%3A15%3A17Z&sr=b&sp=racwdxyltmei&sig=xxx
BlobSASUrl = https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/demo/spring-flowers.jpg?sv=2023-11-03&st=2023-12-07T07%3A00%3A17Z&se=2023-12-07T07%3A15%3A17Z&sr=b&sp=racwdxyltmei&sig=xxxxx
```

Copied the **`BlobSASUrl`** and pasted it into the browser it worked perfectly in public with **`15 minutes`** expiry time.

**Browser:**
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer I already found it, I misconfigured the network setting to allow selected IP and container open anonymous access. The correct way is like your answer to let open public in-network access and private ( no anonymous access) in-container level